# Meteor: insert a list item into a collection from another collection onClick of a button? error. internal server error

Tags: javascript, meteor, insert, meteor-methods

I have a list of objects called categories, within them is an array of other objects which are the posts within that category, where **id :129** is the *category id* and **ID  :100** is the *posts id*. it looks like this

[image]

In my html i have a button on each category item, that when clicked, it takes that category and its contents, (posts and other data) and inserts it into a new collection that is supposed to be specific to the user, like a bookmark. i.e how tumblar, flipboard, google currents, zite have streams personal to the user, and when you follow a topic, the posts in that topic reflect on your personal stream.

However i'm getting two errors

on the chrome console i get:

#### Error invoking Method 'addTimeline': Internal server error [500]

in my terminal i get:

#### Exception while invoking method 'addTimeline' ReferenceError: doc is not defined

my server js is like this

```
Meteor.methods({
    'addTimeline': function(data){
        Timeline.insert(doc);
    }
});
```

My client js looks like this

```
Timeline.allow({
  insert: function (userId) {
     return (userId);
  }
 });
Template.CategoriesMain.events({
  'click .addFav':  function() {
    Meteor.call('addTimeline');

  }
});
```

My html looks like this

```
<template name="CategoriesMain">

<ul>
  {{#each articles}}
    <li>
      <a href="/catsingle/CategorySingle/{{_id}}"><h2>{{name}}</h2></a>
    </li>
    <button type="checked" name="button" class="addFav">add to fav</button>
  {{/each}}
```

truth is i'm quite new to meteor so i have been trying to hack and sash so i'm not sure what the problem is exactly or how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two errors.

**Error 1**

In your method `addTimeline`, you use the variable `doc`, but you name your parameter `data`.

**Error 2**

In your click event handler, you call the method `addTimeline`, but you don't pass it any argument (the `data` parameter will be `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. could you explain to me how i can choose the right arguments and parameters? It really confuses me. when you say "but you don't pass it any argument (the data parameter will be undefined" are you saying the result will be undefined, or i have to put undefined as a parameter? Also is 'data' the correct parameter to use in this instance? @pepeL-G

Comment: @Drakata, As with all functions you create, it's up to you to name your parameters. In this case, I find both `data` and `doc` acceptable names, but I would go with `doc`. The argument should the be the JavaScript object you want to insert into the collection. Note: I haven't read through your entire post, I just took a look at the code and told you the errors I could find, I don't know what you're actually trying to do.